# ¿Cómo sería este programa?

Tags: java

Determinar si es un año bisiesto. Realice un programa donde determine en base al año si es bisiesto o no. Un año es bisiesto (un día extra): - Si es divisible por 400 O - Si es divisible por 4, pero no por 100.

Comment: La divisibilidad la puedes detectar mirando si el resto de la división (operador `%`) es cero. Por ejemplo `año % 4 == 0` implica que el año es divisible por 4. El resto es cosa de usar unos `if`/`else` con cuidado

Comment: Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en Español, da un [tour] y revisa [ask] para que puedas formular una pregunta que sea aceptada por la comunidad. Muestra lo que has intentado.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Answer (score -1):

Las reglas de un año bisiesto son:

- El año debe ser divisible entre 4
- Si el año es divisible entre 100, no es bisiesto, a menos que tambien sea divisible entre 400.

En Java quedaria algo como esto:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bisiesto {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Año a revisar: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int anio = scanner.nextInt();
        if(anio%4 == 0 && (anio%100 != 0 || anio%400 == 0)) {
            System.out.println("El año si es bisiesto.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("El año no es bisiesto.");
        }

        scanner.close();
    }
}
```